# Powershell Script Check if folder doesnt contain random file other than specific file, It will Create New File

Tags: powershell

Im quite new to powershell script. Currently I wan to find the files in the path, if the path doesnt contain .txt file, it will create a new text file. Is there anyway i can do that?

I've tried with script below but it came out with the error parameter eq not found

> if (Test-Path $path -Exclude *.bak -eq false)

[image]

Comment: so ... what have you tried? what did not work as expected? what errors did you get? also, please add that info to your Question ... not in a comment. [*grin*]

Comment: ive amended my question

Comment: you have tried to tell `Test-Path` to process a parameter named `-eq`. [*grin*] since that cmdlet returns a boolean ... there is no need for that test. however, if you really want to use such, you need to ... 1st - demarcate the cmdlet and the comparison steps. 2nd - test for the boolean `$False`, not the string `false`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Get-ChilItem` as our base here and pass the properties we are searching for such as the the .txt extension and do something with it. Using the `if` conditional statement, we can accomplish this like so:

```
#assign the objects returned from Get-ChildItem to $loc
$Loc = Get-ChildItem C:\users\Abraham

    #Check to see if the extension is found using a -notcontains conditional operator
    #(against the property of .extension of each returned object (paths))
    #See here https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/contains/ 
    if($Loc.extension -notcontains ".txt"){

       #this  is our "DO", where the condition was met above
       #so we will create the text file named "MyText"
       #(by passing the "fullname" property which contains the full path of the objects in $Loc.)
       New-Item -Path $Loc.fullname -Name MyText.txt}
```

What we're doing here is referencing the properties of the returned objects from `Get-ChildItem` by using whats called, "Dot Notation": `$loc.Name, $loc.fullname, $loc.LastWriteTime, etc`

You can get a list of the properties and methods(stuff you can do to the object(s)) by piping any cmdlet to `Get-Member`. `Get-ChildItem | GM` #GM is an alias for Get-Member.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to use Test-Path to check if a certain file is present and if not create it?

Something like this then perhaps?

```
$path = 'D:\Test'
if (!(Test-Path -Path "$path\*" -Filter '*.txt' -PathType Leaf)) { 
    $null = New-Item -Path $path -Name ('Test_{0:ddMMyyyy}.txt' -f (Get-Date))
}
```